# How to connect to AWS ElastiCache Cluster from AWS CloudFront using Node.js?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, redis, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-elasticache

I am new to AWS CloudFront and AWS in general. I have a Next.js (React SSR framework) website which I deployed onto AWS using `serverless-nextjs` (https://github.com/serverless-nextjs/serverless-next.js). However, I also need some sort of caching for my web app. I decided to use redis ElastiCache from AWS. I created an redis ElastiCache Cluster on the AWS console.

My attempt:

I setup the code for connecting to the redis ElastiCache like this:

```js
import redis from 'redis';
...

export async function getServerSideProps() { // Server side function for Next.js
    const cache = redis.createClient(6379, "{PRIMARY-ENDPOINT-URL-AWS}");
}
```

and I run the website locally on my PC. However, I get a timeout error from redis: `Error: connect ETIMEDOUT`.

How would I be able to connect to the redis ElastiCache Cluster from CloudFront and on my local PC?

Screenshot of the redis ElastiCache Cluster window:

[redis ElastiCache](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gYu0g.png)

Comment: Are you able to hit the Redis cluster endpoint manually, for example with telnet (`telnet long-aws-url 6379`)? If not, it's probably to do with the networking settings on your cluster and you should investigate the subnets and security groups (is it allowing public traffic or traffic from at least your IP, etc.).

Comment: Do you have Redis Auth which requires Encryption Intransit enabled?

Comment: @ZacAnger I don't have `telnet` on my Mac. Could you tell me how to do it with `ssh`?

Comment: @BaluVyamajala Is that with AWS? How would I check?

Comment: You can't ssh to managed Redis, because it's managed :). I would recommend having a few handy tools like `telnet`, `curl`, and `nc` installed anyway. You can install telnet with `brew install telnet`.

If you didn't configure auth and encryption when you created the Elasticache cluster, you probably don't have it set up, I don't think those are the defaults.

If you can safely rule out networking settings (that is, if you can hit that port at that URL from your machine and lambda), and can rule out having encryption in transit enabled, then it  could be a code issue.

Comment: @ZacAnger Okay I got this as my output: ```Trying <ip-address>...
telnet: connect to address  <ip-address>.: Operation timed out
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host```.

Comment: Sounds to me like either subnets or security groups then. If you update your question with details on those it'll be easier to help (screenshots would work fine).

Comment: @jacnial 'AUTH token last modified date' and 'Encryption at-rest' right on the home page.

Comment: Updated with screenshot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You **can't connect to ES from outside** (i.e. your local workstation) of AWS directly. ES domains are designed to be only accessible from within your resources (e.g. instances) in the same VPC as your ES domain. From [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/red-ug/accessing-elasticache.html#access-from-outside-aws):

> Elasticache is a service **designed to be used internally to your VPC**. External access is discouraged due to the latency of Internet traffic and security concerns. However, if external access to Elasticache is required for test or development purposes, it **can be done through a VPN**.

The only way to enable connections from outside AWS to your ES is if you establish a VPN connection between home/work network or Direct Connect as explained in [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/red-ug/elasticache-vpc-accessing.html#elasticache-vpc-accessing-data-center):

> This scenario is also supported providing there is connectivity between the customers’ VPC and the data center either **through VPN or Direct Connect**.

However, for quick, ad-hock setup you can use **ssh tunnel** between your local workstation and ES domain. This will require some jump/basion EC2 instance which the tunnel will go through.

Comment: Okay but the `serverless-nextjs` deploys the website to AWS CloudFront. Even if I upload onto there and go on the website with the CloufFront URL, it still gives me the error. And even if it did work, would the only way to test the website locally would be to use the VPN/SSH Tunnel solution mentioned?

Comment: @Jacnial CloudFront does not work inside VPC. Its same as if you were trying to connect from home/work.

Comment: Oh I see. Is it possible to put it with a VPC?

Comment: @Jacnial No its not. But are you sure you need fully managed 3 node ES cluster? Maybe you can deploy your own one on an instance or docker?

Comment: I am not sure what that is, it already created those when I created my redis ElastiCache cluster. I deployed a redis DB on docker locally, and it worked well on my local machine, but I am not sure where I could run it on AWS for my website.

Comment: Okay, I'll look at Fargate. And the answer still doesn't mention how I could do it for a production website on Node.js. Like how would I do connect through a VPN through Node.js code? I'll accept your answer anyways since it tells me the approach. Thank you.

Comment: @Jacnial Thanks. I would suggest making new question once you start integrating AWS Fargate with details of your setup.